# How to make read a value from application-dev.properties

Tags: java, spring

I have the dev profile so i was trying to read the "spring.rabbitmq.encodedEnabled" value from application-dev.properties, and when i try to use this snippet of code:
  `@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.encodedEnabled}") private Boolean encodedEnabled;`
spring throw a NullPointerException on encodedEnabled variable. Could someone help me?

Comment: Are other values from the file read? Is the `dev` profile activated? In order to help you, we need more information. Please [edit] the post and provide a [MRE].

Comment: You very likely don't have the `dev` profile enabled. Here's an excellent tutorial on profiles in Spring: https://www.sivalabs.in/spring-boot-profiles-tutorial/

Comment: I entered the same value also in the application.properties, so any case it should be read that value.

Comment: `@Value` like `@Autowired` doesn't work on `static`.

Comment: If i delet static on the variable it doesn't work anyway

Comment: If it doesn't work without `static` then the class/instance isn't managed by Spring and `@Value` like `@Autowired` won't work anyway.

Comment: how can i check if the class is managed by Spring

Answer (score 0):

you should use @Profile("dev") annotation in your class

Comment: It doesn't work anyway

Comment: do you run at dev profile ? for example if you are using intellij you can change to dev env inside run button configuration.

Comment: yes the project run with dev profile

Comment: can you try "private Boolean encodedEnabled"  without static

Comment: it's not static anymore